# Is there any site to download patents in bulk in PDF format?

Tags: patent-services

I want to download thousands of patent documents in PDF format for a patent search system. I want them in zipped files which have thousands of patents.

Does Google bulk patent provide this?

Answer (score 5):

Try also [USPTO Electronic Bulk Data Products](http://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/electronic-bulk-data-products).

You might also try to use [Googles's tesseract ocr](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) project to perform OCR on PDFs to extract searchable text, for that you would need very good IT specialists.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, google makes several different [downloads](http://www.google.com/googlebooks/uspto.html) available in a zip format. This data is from the USPTO and does not include OCR'd version of older patents.

EDIT

Google no longer offers this service. Go directly to the [USPTO bulk download page](https://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/bulk-data-products)

Comment: Do the googled ziped format contains patents in zipped format .. @George White

Comment: If you follow the link you can see what types of files are available. Rather thn PDF, the full image patents are tiffs. It looks like they are grouped by the week of issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following [iMacros plugin](http://imacros.net/) script to download PDFs of every patent on a Google patents search results page:

```
TAG POS={{!loop}} TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Overview
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#\\:4" BUTTON=0
BACK
```

So, suppose your search is https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=pts&hl=en&q=ininventor:%22Nikola+Tesla%22&num=100 . This patent search returned 94 results, so I make sure "num=100" (or any number ≥94). Change the "Max" field of iMacro's "Play" tab to the number of results (94 in this example) and click the "Play (Loop)" button. iMacro will download all the PDFs. ☺

Answer (score 1):

The best source is directly from the USPTO from the [USPTO Bulk Data Download Site](https://bulkdata.uspto.gov) under Multi-Page Portable Document Format (PDF) Images.  Note these are image PDFs, not text based PDFs. So also download the bulk data text files.  And to best utilize classification you will want to also download the Master Classification File.

Answer (score 1):

Try poxoq for patents (http://poxoq.com/). You can bulk download thousands of patents very quickly in a folder of your choice. I really recommend it.

Comment: This seems to be a good answer to the problem. Would you anyways please state your affiliatians if any?

Comment: Seems to cost...

Answer (score 1):

I made a video on how to download patents in bulk from google patents https://youtu.be/iltplMR_hOA

In the video above I go through how to use firefox and chrome in order to download google patents in bulk. You will be able to do the process without writing a single line of code.

Configuring Firefox to open the links in the same tab with add-ons or extensions **New Tab Override**

Second, we will use an **Open Multiple URLs** firefox addon to open multiple URLs at once.

We are done firefox close it now.

Open Chrome and add an extension **Instant Data Scraper**

Now go to patents.google.com and search for your keyword and change number of results from 10 to 100.

Now click on Instant Data Scrapper and it will copy all the links at once from the result section. Now the extension will ask you to locate the next button on the page do it. Once you have located the next button it will copy all the links from the pages.

Now Instant Data Scrapper will give you an option to download the links in the csv. Download it and locate the pdf links coloum. Copy all the links.

Go to firefox and use open multiple URLs and paste the links in there.

Once the pdf links are opened all the pdf will start to download automatically in the firefox.

If anyone faces any problem watch the video.

Comment: While a Youtube video is helpful, link only answers are discouraged. Could you at least provide a brief description in the answer of your solution?

Comment: Alright, I can provide a brief answer. I will edit and add some more information in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

As others have said downloading PDF documents in a single bulk download is probably best done from the USPTO Bulk Data Products page.

If you wanted to download PDF files programmatically as needed rather than all at one time, my company [IP Street](http://www.ipstreet.com/) can help you with this.

We are faster and more constant than scraping Google Patents (they do things to purposely break you crawlers) and we don't rate limit you. We are way cheaper and more convenient than downloading and maintaining you own database.  The documents are already OCR'd and ready to be used as HTML.

Please reach out if you think this might help your work.

Comment: -1 This doesn't answer the question (which is explicitly about bulk downloads), and only serves to promote your product (that is, is spam).