# Bulk extraction of patent information

Tags: legal, databases, extraction

Are there any patent databases, besides USPTO database, that allows bulk extraction of patent information free of charge / for a minimal fee?

Comment: Related answer https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/5999/18033

Comment: A little more info. How many patents are you trying to download at one time?

Comment: Hello Eric.. Around 500 patents.

Comment: Have you tried searching this site with the [bulk-download] keyword? There are some existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

'poxoq for patents' is a search and retrieval tool which can be used to easily download publications in PDF format of granted patents, patent applications and utility models from over 90 countries.  http://www.poxoq.com/   This might be worth trying altho the new license rules permit only the first 10 pages to be downloaded

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can do this with the EPO site although I've never done it myself. Try [this page](http://www.epo.org/searching-for-patents/data/linked-open-data.html#tab-1) for more information.