# WIPO translate-Patentscope download

Tags: patent-applications, patent-services, patent-search

Is there a simpler way to download machine translated patent text from WIPO Patentscope, beside copy-paste text from WIPO window? 
Is it possible to download/export bibliographical data + translated full patent text downloade all in one document?
Question relates only to use of the WIPO Translate tool. 
Any hint is wellcome. Thank you

Comment: You can check https://www.wipo.int/patentscope/en/data/ for information about their API. I don't think it is free however.

Comment: You also may want to check out this answer: https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/5996/is-there-any-site-to-download-patents-in-bulk-in-pdf-format

Comment: Haven't tried it but this looks promising: http://www.poxoq.com/. Not free however.

Comment: not wipo, but espacenet (has a lot of patent data): https://worldwide.espacenet.com/. they allow you to print the translation to pdf.  see also https://www.epo.org/searching-for-patents/helpful-resources/patent-translate.html#tab1. I do not know how to access the translation via their open access API which definitely does provide all other types of patent information